# Saving a x y coordinates in a 2d vector3 array then printing the results to the console C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to save the coordinates of placed tiles after I use a x and y loop to place them. What I would like to do is to take the coordinates of those tiles and place them in a 2d array, or save them somewhere so that when the level loads with the tiles, the coordinates of those tiles will be saved and I can use them later. I'm trying to use those points for the player, so he can travel from point to point, one step at a time.

I'm not sure if im going about it correctly and would like to be able to print the coordinates in the console to see if they were saved.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MapGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform tilePrefab;
    public Vector2 mapSize;

    [Range(0, 1)]
    public float tileOutline;
    public float[] tilePointX;
    public Vector3[,] positionArray;
    public Vector3 tilePosition;

    void Start()
    {

        MapGeneratorMethod();

    }

    public void MapGeneratorMethod()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < mapSize.x; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mapSize.y; y++)
            {
                Debug.Log("TEST");
                tilePosition = new Vector3(-mapSize.x / 2 + 0.5f + x, 0, -mapSize.y / 2 + 0.5f + y);
                //getposition of tile = position array
                Transform newTile = Instantiate(tilePrefab, tilePosition, Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.right * 90)) as Transform;
                newTile.localScale = Vector3.one * (1 - tileOutline);

            }
        }

    }

    public void findTilePoint()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < mapSize.x; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mapSize.y; y++)
            {
                tilePosition = new Vector3(-mapSize.x / 2 + 0.5f + x, 0, -mapSize.y / 2 + 0.5f + y);
                positionArray[x,y] = tilePosition;
                Debug.Log(x);

            }
        }
       // Debug.Log(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you do this in a slightly different way, instead of storing the positions of the tiles in a 2D array I would stores references to the transforms of the tiles in a 2D array. i.e.

```
public float tileOutline;
public float[] tilePointX;
public Transform[,] tilesArray;
public Vector3 tilePosition;

void Start()
{

    MapGeneratorMethod();

}

public void MapGeneratorMethod()
{
    tilesArray = new transform[mapSize.x, mapSize.y];

    for (int x = 0; x < mapSize.x; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < mapSize.y; y++)
        {
            Debug.Log("TEST");
            tilePosition = new Vector3(-mapSize.x / 2 + 0.5f + x, 0, -mapSize.y / 2 + 0.5f + y);
            //getposition of tile = position array
            Transform newTile = Instantiate(tilePrefab, tilePosition, Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.right * 90)) as Transform;
            newTile.localScale = Vector3.one * (1 - tileOutline);


            tilesArray[x,y] = newTile;
        }
    }
```

By doing it this way you still are able to get the position of the tiles using `tilesArray[x,y].GetPosition()` but you will also be able to get any component connected to the tile whenever you need. also note that i added the line

```
tilesArray = new transform[mapSize.x, mapSize.y];
```

at the beginning of the function. you should really initialise the array this way before using it. As a final note you are able to pass a vector2 or vector3 directly to the debug.log as follows.

```
public void findTilePoint()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < mapSize.x; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < mapSize.y; y++)
        {
            vector3 tilePosition = tilesArray[x,y].GetPosition()
            Debug.Log(tilePosition);

        }
    }
   // Debug.Log(x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks unholy sheep! Much appreciated!